# (python-docx how) to add a variable text?

Tags: python, excel, python-docx

i want to extract a data from an excel using pandas and writing it on a word document thanks to python-docx. The problem is that the function document.add_paragraph() only takes 'text' as an input.

Do you see a solution please ?

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: What do you mean by "a data"? What do you want the result to look like?

Comment: Hi Dan. i mean the value of a cell for exemple. If A is an array for exemple. I want to write in my code document.add_paragraph(A[0][0]) for getting the first cell written in my word document.

Comment: Written how? Like an ordinary number? Did you try using `str()` to convert numbers to text? Did you encounter any errors, or did this not do what you wanted?

Comment: I feel kind of stupid for not having tried str()... thank you very much Dan for this who is definitely going to save me for my academic project

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.